# Regionalization of Verification Code Calls During Sign-In

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We're using Azure AD B2C with custom policies on one of our projects.  We enable mobile phone 2FA for all our users.

When a user signs in, they have the option of having their verification code sent via text message or phone call.  If they choose the phone call option, the voice that rings them is American and instructs them to press the "pound sign".  This is confusing our UK based user base, as we know the '#' symbol as 'hash' and have the symbol '£' for pound (which isn't available on a phone keypad).

I've not been able to find a way to regionalize the tenant or policy.  I've found a web page about localizing the language part, but not the region/sub-culture element.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization

Ideally we're looking to be able to define the culture settings to 'en-GB' rather than just 'en'.  Assuming it would then produce a UK voice that makes no reference to the 'pound sign'?  Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the localization of the phone call should happen automatically, regardless of custom policy settings. You can set a custom voice message by following the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-mfa-mfasettings#set-up-a-custom-message). I don't know if it allows you to distinguish between American and British English, but if you are just worried about UK-based users, you could just replace the American English version entirely.

Comment: Thanks, we discovered this when researching but it's all for Azure AD (which like you say fully supports full customisation). For Azure AD B2C though, having this service enabled doesn't activate the necessary blades in the Azure Portal sadly

Comment: That's strange, the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/multi-factor-authentication?pivots=b2c-custom-policy) states that it integrates directly with the AD MFA, which I assumed meant that it would integrate with any customizations made. Hopefully they get working on that.

Also (you likely already did this, but doesn't hurt to ask), did you make sure your browser's locale settings were set appropriately when testing as that is how AD determines what language to use in the call.